# "__import__(name) ImportError: No module named fields " in runbot module

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I'm trying to install Runbot in my odoo local system, followed every step explained here: http://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/installing-and-configuring-your-own-runbot/

downloaded current working runbot from https://github.com/odoo/odoo-extra  and try to install the runbot module, giving an error like this **__import__(name)
ImportError: No module named fields**. don't know why coming to this error and odoo not working if remove runbot module odoo works properly. is anything doing wrong . pls, help me, anyone, thanks in adv.

Comment: The steps listed in [http://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/installing-and-configuring-your-own-runbot/](http://www.odoo.yenthevg.com/installing-and-configuring-your-own-runbot/).. do they include anything about downloading code from [https://github.com/odoo/odoo-extra](https://github.com/odoo/odoo-extra)?

Comment: yes, have to take runbot folder from github put in odoo/addons path. then make it install in odoo.

Answer (score 1):

This module is not ported yet for odoo-10.
This module is for older version of odoo.

Comment: is any alternative option for testing a developed modules in odoo10.

Comment: You can port the `runbot` module yourself using OCA's guidelines [here](https://github.com/OCA/maintainer-tools/wiki/Migration-to-version-10.0)